# yii extension for simple organization of webpage content

Tags: jquery, yii, yii-extensions

I want to let user to create and manage boxes of dynamic content (image/video/text...). These boxes should be resizeable and user should be able to change their position on the website (similarly to windows in MS Win OS). I couldn't find anything like this on the internet (maybe because I don't know what is it called). Is there any yii or jQuery extension for this?

Comment: Like this: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-resizable-draggable-resize-drag-tutorial-example/ ?

Comment: The answer strongly depends on how close it should resemble Ms Windows. If it is one of the keypoints of your task, there is ExtJs (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/desktop/desktop.html ), but it has some overhead involved. Otherwise, you should use solution proposed by @jagsler,  just make sure that _stop_ event in jQueryUI draggable and jQueryUI resizable sends new proportions and coordinates to server by ajax for storing them.